# "line number not found" error in confg/routes file in play2.3

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

my routes file in play gives this error

**error: cannot find symbol

In /home/smat/practical/Stocks/conf/routes (line number not found)**

here is my routes file

```
 # Routes
    # This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
    # ~~~~

    # Home page
    GET     /                           controllers.Application.index

    # Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
    GET     /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

    # stocks
    GET     /stocks/add                 controllers.Stocks.add
    POST    /stocks/save                controllers.Stocks.save
    GET     /register               controllers.Stocks.registerUser
    POST    /register               controllers.Stocks.registerUser
```

please help

sorry i forget to share errors on terminal

> **[error] /home/smat/practical/Stocks/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/contrllers/routes.java:8:
>   error: cannot find symbol [error] public static final
>   contrllers.ReverseStocks Stocks = new contrllers.ReverseStocks();
>   [error]                               ^ [error]   symbol:   class
>   ReverseStocks [error]   location: package contrllers
>
> [error]
>   /home/smat/practical/Stocks/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/contrllers/routes.java:11:
>   error: package contrllers.javascript does not exist [error] public
>   static final contrllers.javascript.ReverseStocks Stocks = new
>   contrllers.javascript.ReverseStocks(); [error]
>   ^ [error]
>   /home/smat/practical/Stocks/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/contrllers/routes.java:16:
>   error: package contrllers.ref does not exist [error] public static
>   final contrllers.ref.ReverseStocks Stocks = new
>   contrllers.ref.ReverseStocks(); [error]
>   ^ [error]
>   /home/smat/practical/Stocks/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/contrllers/routes.java:8:
>   error: cannot find symbol [error] public static final
>   contrllers.ReverseStocks Stocks = new contrllers.ReverseStocks();
>   [error]
>   ^ [error]   symbol:   class ReverseStocks [error]   location: package
>   contrllers [error]
>   /home/smat/practical/Stocks/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/contrllers/routes.java:11:
>   error: package contrllers.javascript does not exist [error] public
>   static final contrllers.javascript.ReverseStocks Stocks = new
>   contrllers.javascript.ReverseStocks(); [error]
>   ^ [error]
>   /home/smat/practical/Stocks/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/contrllers/routes.java:16:
>   error: package contrllers.ref does not exist [error] public static
>   final contrllers.ref.ReverseStocks Stocks = new
>   contrllers.ref.ReverseStocks(); [error]
>   ^**

Comment: Leave a blank line in the end.... lets see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
package contrllers.ref does not exist
```

It looks like you made a misspell somewhere in the source files. Try to lookup your project directories for files with "contrllers" instead of "controllers".